# Is it okay to just re-tag C++ to C?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I see a plenty of questions that post pure C code and are tagged C++ or C and C++. Let's just assume that nothing in the content implies anything C++-related. And just being compiled by a C++ compiler instead of C changes nothing.

I edited a few by removing the C++ tag and add C if not already there, as it seemed like the proper thing.

Now I'm getting unsure, so better ask whether it is desired or not. (having 3k+ reputation makes those edit just happen without review... guess the author gets an alert and can roll back, still I'd welcome confirmation to either way.)

Comment: Don't do that without asking. C++ code can look like C but nevertheless be compiled as C++. Changing the tag to C changes the question.

Comment: indeed it changes the question, and C++ tag creates a serious scope drift: guy asks some problem with fopen of malloc and gets answers to use iostreams new and other unrelated stuff...

Comment: Well if they don't specify well enough what they want, then you should ask for clarifications. But if it's tagged C++, assume a C++ compiler and C++ semantics (i.e. `SomeType *foo = malloc(...)` is invalid C++ but idiomatic C - don't just retag if you don't know for sure what the target language is).

Comment: `And just being compiled by a C++ compiler instead of C changes nothing.` It changes _everything_.

Comment: @BalogPal This is specifically about questions where there is an existing C++ tag being *removed*, and replaced with a C tag. There is no reason to assume they're not interested in C++ answers (iostreams etc) if they themselves tagged the question with C++. You can't make that judgement for them.

Answer (score 13):

Even if their code is pure C, they could be using a C++ compiler, which might change the question.  Better to just comment and ask the author of the question to clarify.

Comment: I'm sure they use C++ compiler, the question stands for content that is NOT influenced by that. -- edited the question to make that more explicit

Comment: @BalogPal If you're sure they're using a C++ compiler, then it's certainly a C++ question and should not be retagged to C.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language. You making the judgement that their question isn't related to C++ seems quite unfair.

Answer (score 9):

Do not confuse the following two things:

- C++ code that looks like C code
- C code

As long as the OP is compiling his/her code using a C++ compiler, their code is C++ code, and their question should be tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

However, it may be of use to politely comment to the OP that their C++ code is rubbish.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm good at it